# ¿Como hacer que el Scroll vertical de un JScrollPane siempre inicie desde la parte mas baja?

Tags: java, java-swing, netbeans-8.2, jtable, scrollbar

estoy haciendo un proyecto en lenguaje de Java para el instituto, para ese proyecto estoy usando una JScrollPane que contiene una JTable y quiero que siempre que se inicie a la Frame donde esta el JScrollPane la barra de scroll siempre este en la parte mas baja del JScrollPane

Comment: Curiosamente el método que te puede servir ([`JScrollPane.scrollRectToVisible()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible-java.awt.Rectangle-)) es miembro de *JComponent*.